# Why does my timer only update when it reaches 1

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a timer that uses the tkinter UI and it only displays the number once it reaches 1 instead of counting down.

```
import time
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
t = IntVar()


def countdown(n):
    while n > 0:
        t.set(n)
        n = n - 1
        time.sleep(1)
        if n == 0:
            print('DONE')

time_l = Label(master, textvariable=t)
time_l.grid()
start_b = Button(text='START', command= lambda: countdown(10))
start_b.grid(padx = 150, pady = 30)
mainloop()
```

Comment: There are dozens of silpmilar questions on this site. Have you done any research before asking?

Comment: you need to use Tkinter after, instead of time.sleep i think

Answer (score 0):

Here, I modified your code. When it hits zero, it exits the program.

Code:

```py
import time
from tkinter import *

master = Tk()
t = IntVar()

time_l = Label(master, text = 0)
time_l.grid()

loop = 1
def countdown(n):
    if n == 0:
        quit()
    n -= 1
    time_l.config(text = n)
    time_l.update()
    master.after(1000, lambda: countdown(n))



start_b = Button(text='START', command = lambda: countdown(10))
start_b.grid(padx = 150, pady = 30)
master.mainloop()
```

Read up about [`window.after()`](https://riptutorial.com/tkinter/example/22870/-after--) and [`config()`](https://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm#button.Button.config-method).

Hope this helps!

Comment: `time_l.update()` is not necessary when `after()` is used.  Also `n -= 1` can be removed if `master.after(1000, countdown, n-1)` is used.

Comment: @acw1668 You mean ```master.after(1000, lambda: countdown(n-1)```. But otherwise the answer is correct, right?